# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/rt/core/UrlTag

Tags: java, jsp, maven, jstl

After refreshing my Maven project this error appears when i'm opening jsp in Tomcat. What is the cause?

jstl dependencies

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
```

This is how I import jstl in jsp

```
 <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: try to remove scope=runtime from your dependencies

Comment: Where exactly did you read/learn that those are the right Maven coordinates for JSTL? I'm not seeing that in e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: @BalusC it's not that I didn't try the one you linked. It didn't work out either so in one post on SO found some guy for whom my current dependencies worked out.

Comment: You're basically mixing JSTL 1.2 API+impl with JSTL 1.1 impl. Get rid of JSTL 1.1, stick to 1.2 and make sure the /WEB-INF/lib of Maven-produced WAR file looks all OK, then reframe if necessary the question once you've eliminated all the wrong things.

Comment: @BalusC It seems like WEB-INF/lib in Target folder doesn't contain JSTL. I changed pom.xml to correct.

Comment: OK, thus your question boils down to "Maven doesn't put JSTL JAR in /WEB-INF/lib of WAR build". That NoClassDefFoundError then simply becomes an "obvious" consequence which you basically don't need to expatiate about in the question, hereby making your question more focused, clear and useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>jstl</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId> 
    <version>1.2</version> 
</dependency>
```